# In spark, can I define more executors than available cores?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

Say I have a total of 4 cores,
What happens if I define num of executors as 8..
Can we share a single core among 2 executors ?
Can the num of cores for a executor be a fraction ?

What is the impact on performance with this kind of config.

Comment: Can the num of cores for an executor be a fraction ? it cannot be and it does not have any sense to allow fraction value.

Comment: What happens if I define num of executors as 8... it does not matter executors are launched based on the resource availability ....  if you are using any RM(like yarn,Mesos) then executors are launched based on the resource availability of the cluster.

Comment: in spark architecture, each cpu core is considered as a slot, and each task/executor will take a single slot and process one partition at a time.... whether core can be shared between executor or not depends on underling hardware architecture. (i.e if architecture has hyperthreading enabled then core is obviously shared between processes).... but in spark perspective, there is no such conf and it does not see in that way.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I observed in spark standalone mode:

The total cores of my system are 4

if I execute spark-shell command with spark.executor.cores=2
Then 2 executors will be created with 2 core each.
[image]
[image]

But if I configure the no of executors more than available cores,
Then only one executor will be created, with the max core of the system.
[image]
[image]

The number of the core will never be of fraction value.
If you assign fraction value in the configuration, you will end up with exception:

[image]

**Feel free to edit/correct the post if anything is wrong.**